# Problem with PHP Cookies and jQuery

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, forms, cookies

I have what it seems to me to be a strange problem.

I have a webpage with a jQuery accordion menu, and some jQUery behaviour, hich is that one:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$("#accordion").accordion({
    collapsible: true,
    active: true,
    autoHeight: false,
    /* Binding to the change event of the accordion. When all panes are collapsed, ui.newHeader will be an empty jQuery object */
    changestart: function(event, ui) {
        if (!ui.newHeader.length) {
            $("#prods_vcts").css("background", "url(images/Fondo_ALT_Products.png)");
            $('#sub2').hide('fast');
            $('#sub4').hide('fast');
        } else {
            $("#prods_vcts").css("background", "url(images/taula_vcts_"
                + ui.newHeader.attr("id") + ".png) no-repeat");
                $('#sub2').hide('fast');
                var descrid = ui.newHeader.attr("id");
                $.post('scripts/mostrar_descr_gral.php', {desc:descrid}, function(data) {
                    $('#sub4').show('fast');
                    $('#sub4').html(data);
                });
        }
    }
});
$('.detail').live('click',function() {
    var subcatid = this.id;
    $.post('mostrar_prods.php', {subcat:subcatid}, function(data) {
        $('#sub4').hide('fast');
        $('#sub2').show('fast');
        $('#sub2').html(data);
    });
    return false;
});
$('form').live('submit', function() {
    var formid = this.id;
    var prodidval = $('#prodid'+formid).val();
    var prodpreuval = $('#prodpreu'+formid).val();
    var prodquantval = $('#prodquant'+formid).val();
    $.post('scripts/carret.php', {idval:prodidval, preuval:prodpreuval, quantval:prodquantval, id:formid}, function(data) {
        $('#sub333').html(data);
    });
    return false;
});
});
```

The PROBLEM is: everything works as expected, until I set a cookie. The idea is that a cookie is set when the user clicks in 'scripts/carret.php'. When a cookie is present, then the accordion works perfectly, but the other two functions don't.

I've TRIED to set the cookie in the first line of the index.php, in the first line of the scripts/carret.php, with the jQuery plugin, etc.; I've tried to change the folder of scripts/carret.php, I've tried the '/', etc. I've checked, and I dont't know anymore.

By the way, that's the content of carret.php:

```
<?php

$qidval = $_REQUEST['idval'];
$qpreuval = $_REQUEST['preuval'];
$qquantval = $_REQUEST['quantval'];

echo '<div id="sub33" style="margin-top:100px; margin-left:80px; position:relative; z-index:2">
<div style="position:absolute; margin-top:0px; text-align:left">
    idval= '.$_REQUEST['idval'].'<br>
    preuval= '.$qpreuval.'<br>
    quantval= '.$qquantval.'<br>
    id= '.$_REQUEST['id'].'
</div>
</div>';
```

And that's it. Any help or suggestion? I'm sure it's something pretty basic that I'm missing, being a newbie!

Thanks!

R

Comment: It's late here, maybe I'm overseeing something, but what do cookies do in your script? where are you setting them? And cookies, also, start from the subsequent request, so if you set it now, it will be available on the next request. Other thing, escape, there are some xss vulnerabilities in your script

Comment: Might be handy if you could provide a link to a page which hosts your code?

Comment: I think I missing something...you're sending a `post $.post('scripts/carret.php'` but picking up `get` vars `$qidval = $_REQUEST['idval'];`?

Comment: Hi! Cookies are set to build a shopping cart with a client id. And yes, the cookie is available, but the two last functions don't work.

Comment: Also, Damien, could you hint those xss problems? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

jk was right it was a problem of using request and a loop when looking for post AND with a cookie: the first result retrieved was the cookie, not the post.